# Continue outside of loop, dice rolling script

Tags: python, dice, rolling-computation

I'm making a dice rolling game. The following code produces an error, saying "continue outside of loop":

```py
import random

repeat="y" or "yes"

while repeat == "y" or "yes"
  print("Rolling the dice")
  print(random.randint(1,6))

repeat = input("Do you wanna roll again Y/N?").lower()

if repeat =="y" or "yes":
  continue
else:
  print("Thanks for rolling")
  break
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: I've transcribed your code from your screenshot, so that others can read it. We prefer to have the code inside the question as text, rather than an external image.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot affect 2 walues as teh same time, chose "y" or "Y" in your expressions.

```
repeat="y"

while (repeat == "y") or (repeat == "yes"):
```

You have to check your indentation too,
repeat = input has to be inside the loop, so you get a new input to check each time.
The final print can be put outside the loop at the very end.

Here is a working example, and you can type anything starting with "y"/"Y" to continue rolling:

```
import random

repeat="y"

while (repeat[0]) == "y":
    print("Rolling the dice")
    print(random.randint(1,6))
    repeat = input("Do you wanna roll again Y/N?").lower()

print("Thanks for rolling")
```